# How do I get the script of a GameObject underneath my selected GameObject? (Unity2D) (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to set some variables in another object (called a chamber) as I leave it.  However I can't seem to access the script of this specific GameObject out of many in the scene.  I get a "not set to an instance of an object" error.

Note that the Senator "knows" what chamber he is in by ID (int) & by name (string).  The Chamber also "knows" there is a Senator there, but not who.  I need to clear the chamber as the Senator object leaves, but I can't get a hold on the script for that specific chamber.

The coding is as follows:

```css
            // Do Work
            rbSenator.transform.position = newPos;
            Senator senatorSc = rbSenator.GetComponent<Senator>();
            originChamberName = senatorSc.GetInChamber();
            goChamber = GameObject.Find(originChamberName);
            Chamber originSc = goChamber.GetComponent<Chamber>();  //******************************** error
            originSc.FreeSeat(originChamber, senatorSeat);
            // Do Work
```

Comment: `GameObject.Find(originChamberName);` is returning null. You need to debug why.

Answer (score 0):

You might be mission rbSenator GameObject.
Let me know that are you assigning that rbSenator GameObject through inspector??
If yes then Checkout that rbSenator field in Inspector during Run Time.
Note: Sometime unity make fields empty during Run Time.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one room that is a child of your object, you can use `GetComponentInChildren<TypeOfYourRoom>()`
If there is multiple, then use a for loop to find the one you want with it's name or something

Comment: The room is not a child of the object, it is a stand-alone object that may contain several senators.  Also there are a bunch of chambers and a bunch of senators. Not sure how a loop would help as I already know the name and ID of the chamber, but apparently Unity won't let me get it using a string.  Again, thanks for the hint.

Comment: Oh ok, didn't understand it that way. Unity does let you find a gameobject by it's name tho, using `GameObject.Find("theName")`.
What you could do is create a custom tag, then get all objects using `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag()` then get the one you want.

Comment: Unity apparently won't accept a string (originChamberName) instead of a literal ("This Chamber").  I can't use a literal because I don't know at the start what chamber the senator is going to be in at runtime. In fact, he should be moving around to different chambers.

Comment: I'm doing that and it works perfectly fine `string myTag = "tag";
        GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(myTag);`